# For loop doesn't work properly for click() method

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I need to emulate multiple button clicks on the website and wanna use **for** loop to get it done but it doesn't work as expected (it clicks only once).

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("increase_your_bet_button").click();
}
```

**UPDATE:** I tried all proposed solutions but nothing worked and it run only once. Played with setTimeout and eventually found a reasonable solution:

```
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("increase_your_bet_button").click();
}, 1000*(i+1));
}
```

Comment: That's weird, is it because you need to add a delay to the loop? I'm not an expert at all, but it might be that the website can't register the clicks quick enough.

Comment: Might be throttled if an event occurs programmatically. There is an `isTrusted` property they can check for. And we don't know what page does with that click

Comment: They probably have code to keep it from being abused... impossible to know without looking at their source. Only thing you can do is play around by using timeouts and find the max rate you can call it.

Comment: Hi! Can you include more code from the website? In particular, anything that might be throttling or blocking your code? As a test for throttling, you may want to add a `setTimeout` in your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.getElementById("increase_your_bet_button").click();
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<button id="increase_your_bet_button" onclick="console.log('Click!')">Click!</button>
```

Comment: Problem is.... you do not know what the code is doing so, yeah it works fine, but something in the black box prevents it.... so this is not really an answer, more like a comment.

Comment: So, should I explain what the code is doing and a possible reason why it broke @epascarello?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('increase_your_bet_button');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicker'));

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  btn.click();
}
```

```html
<button id="increase_your_bet_button">Increase your bet</button>
```

To solve this try using an asynchronous loop, such as:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('increase_your_bet_button');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicker'));

let i = 0;

// Click every millisecond.
function clickTenTimes() {
  btn.click();

  i++;
  if (i < 10)
    setTimeout(clickTenTimes, 1);
}

clickTenTimes();
```

```html
<button id="increase_your_bet_button">Increase your bet</button>
```

Comment: Loop is still going to be the same thing, you are just offsetting it by a millisecond. Probably going to have to adjust the 1 to a larger number to avoid the throttling.